# saving a captured packet in TCPDump format (Java)

Tags: java, packet, tcpdump, jpcap

I want to save a captured packet in TCPDump format. I'm using Java with JPCap library. However, I'm not able to use JpcapWriter.writePacket() function, it gives me a JVM error.
This is the code that is causing the JVM error:
    captor=JpcapCaptor.openDevice(interfaceList[interfaceNumber], 65535, true, 20);
    captor.setFilter("ip and tcp",true);

```
JpcapWriter writer=JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(captor,"pass.txt");

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      //capture a single packet
      Packet packet=captor.getPacket();
      //save it into the opened file
      writer.writePacket(packet);

    }
writer.close();
```

Any other way to save it into a file in TCPformat?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you are calling the method for writing packet. The normal way I used to write packets is

```
JpcapCaptor captor=JpcapCaptor.openDevice(device[index], 65535, false, 20);
JpcapWriter writer=JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(captor,"filename");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  Packet packet=captor.getPacket();
    writer.writePacket(packet);
 }
writer.close();
```

It save TCPDump Format Packets.